# How update text based on HTML tags

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

I have a very basic example:

```
 <div><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit</span>consectetur adipiscing</div>
```

I want to replace word "dolor" to "some_another_word" when it around of tag's `<div>...</div>`. The "dolor" word can place both inside and outside the `div`'s

My current code is next:

```
$html = '<div><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit</span>consectetur adipiscing</div>';

$docs = new \DOMDocument();
$docs->loadHTML( $html );

$els = $docs->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach ( $els as $node ) {
    if ( 'div' === $node->nodeName ) {
        $node->textContent = str_replace('dolor', 'some_another_word', $node->textContent);
    }
}

var_dump( $docs->saveHTML() );
```

The result of my code is:

```
<html><body><div>Lorem ipsum some_another_word sit amet, elit consectetur adipiscing</div></body></html>
```

I am losing `span` tag that I need. How can I prevent it?

Comment: `span` is a childnode of `div`. You have to check if your div has no childnodes - then replace it's `nodevalue`, else - go deeper.

Comment: @u_mulder submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: No) This is really not an answer, answer should contain some code, but I'm lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `XPath` expression to target, quite precisely, the content that you wish to manipulate if you craft the query correctly. The following should give an idea how you can apply that idea.

```
$html = '<div><span style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit</span>consectetur adipiscing</div>';
$word = 'dolor';
$replace = '#### banana ####';

try{

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->validateOnParse = false;
    $dom->standalone=true;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=true;
    $dom->substituteEntities=true;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->formatOutput=false;
    $dom->loadHTML( $html );

    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    libxml_clear_errors();


    if( !empty( $errors ) ) {
        throw new Exception( implode( PHP_EOL, $errors ) );
    }
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

    /* The XPath expression */
    $query='//div/span[ contains( text(),"'.$word.'") ]';

    $col=$xp->query( $query );
    if( !empty( $col ) ){
        foreach( $col as $index => $node ){
            $node->nodeValue = str_replace( $word, $replace, $node->nodeValue );
        }

        /* output to browser or save to file */
        echo $dom->saveHTML();  

    } else {
        throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Empty nodelist - XPath query %s failed', $query ) );
    }
    $dom=$xp=null;
}catch( Exception $e ){
    printf( 'Caught Exception -> Trace:%s Message:%s Code:%d', $e->getTraceAsString(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode() );
}
```